# how to make a date as selected in ui-datepicer deponding on other ui-date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two ui-date picker calendars.

when I select date from the first ui-date picker then the second will shows first date+2 as selected

I.e. I have selected 07/02/2012 from first calendar then the second caladar have 07/04/2012 as selected

See my code

```
$(function(){
                // Datepicker
                $('#datepicker_In').datepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    minDate: 0  
                });
                $('#datepicker_Out').datepicker({
                    inline: true,
                    minDate: 0
                });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
```

Please replay

I have tried a lot but not..........

Thanks a lot

I need to display next 2nd day not the next Month please replay

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you your date format is in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. You could hook into the `datepicker_In` change event, and read the selected value, increment that value by 2 months (as requested) and then set `datepicker_Out` value to the incremented Date.

```
$('#datepicker_In').change(function() {
    var currentDate = $("#datepicker_In").val();

    var newDate = new Date(currentDate);
    var cDate = (newDate.getMonth() + 2) + "/" + newDate.getDate() + "/" + newDate.getFullYear(); 


   $('#datepicker_Out').val(cDate);
});
```

Comment: many many thanks, but because of the minDate: 0 it's not working, i need to set the minDate ( displable previous date ) and this too . Please reply